# Why specifying linetype in bsplines plot the resulting plot looks like three dimensional with one point connected to multiple other points

Tags: r, plot

I'm generating some data for bsplines in R and I've encountered some weird behavior! If I plot the function without specifying line type, the curve looks okay. When I specify the line type, I get a plot where each point is connected with other points and I haven't been able to figure out why. Here is some reproducible code and the subsequent plots. Any explanation is much appreciated!

```
library(bsplines2)
x <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
knots <- unname(quantile(x))[3]
Xtmp<-bSpline(x, knots=knots, intercept=T)         
true.beta<-c(-0.25, 0.5, -0.4, 0.6, -0.3)
simcurve <- c(Xtmp%*%true.beta)

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(x, simcurve, col = 'green')
plot(x, simcurve, col = 'blue', type = 'l')        # same curve with line type set to line

dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue here was due to lack of ordering the values by the spline variable, x. The following should work

```
data<- data.frame(x, simcurve)
data2<- data[order(x), ]
plot(data2[, 1], data2[, 2], type = 'l')
```